# Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing / Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a basic spring boot rest application and angular application. (Using JWT)

However, I can not make any request because of this error:(even I add `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` to response header

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Here is the security configuration:

```java
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
// ...
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(WebUrls.API.API + WebUrls.LOGIN.LOGIN,
                        WebUrls.API.API + WebUrls.LOGIN.REGISTER,
                        WebUrls.API.API + WebUrls.LOGIN.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

Here is the place where I am adding cors headers:

```java
@Component
public class MyCorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if there's some security measure stopping you, and you don't understand it, the __very last__ thing you should do is google for 'how do I disable this thing I do not understand'.

Comment: Can you try this? `public class MyCorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter`

Comment: @wak786 this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below configuration to make this work. This enables CORS requests from any origin to any endpoint in the application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted `MyCorsFilter` and created this class and it works, but I don't understand the difference between my solution and you provided. `MyCorsFilter` will also add **CORS headers** in response for any endpoints?

Comment: In Spring boot, WebMvcConfigurer interface provides a abstract implementation for the CORS Mapping and hence we have to provide our impl. to acheive the CORS policy.

The one you added was an filter not an configuration. The spring container needs configuration for CORS.

Comment: Thank Kapil, my last question is that because we have disabled cors in this line ` http.cors().and().csrf().disable()` , we don't need to set up like this one `registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");` ?

Comment: Correct, you don't have to setup that one. There are multiple ways boot provides to do so. So, this is one of the ways.